# How to reduce Microsoft Exchange suggested time minimum duration?

Tags: exchange, outlook, development

Microsoft Outlook, using Exchange backend has the ability to suggest a meeting time regarding all attendees agenda.

If the meeting has a duration less than 30 minutes, the assistant is not able to suggest a time window.

Is it possible to lower this value ?

[image: Error from the owa portal]

My Exchange version is 2010 (sic).

To give a bit more background, I'm actually calling the [GetUserAvailability method of the Exchange Web Service library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.getuseravailability?view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_ExchangeService_GetUserAvailability_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_AttendeeInfo__Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_TimeWindow_Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_AvailabilityData_Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_AvailabilityOptions_). I'm looking for free slots in a calendar populated with 20 minutes meetings.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, the minimum duration of the scheduling assistant is 30 minutes on the OWA by default, it should be made by design. If you want to modify the default duration, you'd better tag your thread with some keywords(e.g. **development**) to get accurate help.

Besides, to avoid the complicated process that modifying the default duration, the feature **Time Scale** on the outlook is one easier and more convenient way to view the free slots via scheduling assistant(According to your requirement, you could select 5 minutes of **Time Scale**, four scale = 20 minutes):
[image]

Comment: "Based on my research" : do you have any reference ?. Regarding your advice to use different time scale, it won't help unfortunately. The actual use case, as I said, is to tinf free slots from an external application, using the exchange web services.

Comment: The thread is for your reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fd8bc08-ff88-4a41-9395-e8766c3529cc/how-to-use-room-finder-for-meetings-less-than-30-minutes?forum=exchangesvrclientslegacy . Besides, I have viewed the OWA mailbox policy and the OWA VD, it seems that no settings could specify the minimum duration, and I also tried to modify the value of -TimeIncrement parameter, but it didn't work.